# QGIS OpenLayers OSM plugin not matching with my imported GIS information

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, openlayers-2

I have imported GIS data into a new QGIS project for our local city website. The files are shapefiles and inside the prj it shows:

> PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_Florida_East_FIPS_0901_Feet",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",656166.6666666665],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-81.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9999411764705882],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",24.33333333333333],UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]

I set the CRS to NAD83 Florida East - ft on each layer I imported and set the OpenStreetMap layer the plugin created to the same CRS. The project settings also has the same CRS however the GIS data I imported is no where near where it is supposed to be. It is on the other side of the world.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you don't mind me saying - the way I would tackle solving this problem is first to work out whether it's the Openlayers layer or the shapefile layer which is in the wrong place. I'd do that by a very simple means - displaying something on the map which I already know works well. If the trusted data also doesn't fit with the basemap it's this that's the problem. If the trusted data doesn't fit with the new data then it's the new data that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the Openlayers plugin receives tiles in EPSG:3857. It works best if you leave the basemap layer and project CRS in that too.

As an alternative, you can use the QuickMapServices plugin. It allows for different **project** CRS as well. But the basemap layer **must** stay in EPSG:3857.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have the project set to EPSG:3857, and the spapefile layer is set to the  NAD83. When I import this layer into AutoCad MAP it successfully syncs with Bing maps without any issues. Not sure what else I can try.

Comment: Can you give the extent of the shapefile, as reported by Rightclick on the layer -> Properties -> Metadata tab -> Properties section? And near which town or village do you expect the data to be?

Comment: Data is in Miami, Florida.

Extent of layer:

Extents
In layer spatial reference system units
xMin,yMin 697507.50,319014.59 : xMax,yMax 945785.44,599195.42
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=lcc +lat_1=30.75 +lat_2=29.58333333333333 +lat_0=29 +lon_0=-84.5 +x_0=600000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs

Comment: Layer CRS should be `EPSG:2236 Florida East (ft-US)`which is transverse mercator; but your last comment looks like `EPSG:2238 Florida North (ft-US)`, a lambert conformal conical projection. You can use `Set Layer CRS` to correct it.